# Disable selecting other cells after didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I need to disable selecting other cells after selecting right cell in my app.
So, if user selects wrong answer, he can select other cell, but if select right answer, he can't do it.
Help me to resolve my problem.
My code is:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSInteger rowNumber = [indexPath row];
NSArray *array = [self getAnswers];
if (rowNumber == 0)
{
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
if (rowNumber == [array[array.count - 2] intValue])
{
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    [_rightAnswersArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_index+1]];
    NSLog(@"rightAnswersArray = %@",_rightAnswersArray);
    for (rowNumber = 1; rowNumber < array.count - 1; rowNumber++)
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    NSLog(@"%hhd",cell.userInteractionEnabled);
    }
}
else
{
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    [_wrongAnswersArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_index+1]];
    NSLog(@"wrongAnswersArray = %@",_wrongAnswersArray);
    [self showComment];
}
}
```

UPD: Solved with this code.

```
if (rowNumber == [array[array.count - 2] intValue])
{
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
[_rightAnswersArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_index+1]];
NSLog(@"rightAnswersArray = %@",_rightAnswersArray);
for (rowNumber = 1; rowNumber < array.count - 1; rowNumber++)
self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should implement `UITableViewDelegate` method

```
// Called before the user changes the selection. Return a new indexPath, or nil, to change the proposed selection.
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

It should look like this

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return _isRightAnswerAlreadySelected ? nil : indexPath;
}
```

`_isRightAnswerAlreadySelected` should be set up in `(void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath`